# What is the next number in the following sequence?

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

1, 6, 5, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, ?

Hint: the task is pattern recognition using basic mathematical operations.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Comment: s this pattern the result of a series based on a starting rule that is then used to construct the rest of the series? Like a Fibonacci series? Or is this a pattern that you arbitrarily dreamed up according to a rule that cannot start a series? –

Answer (score 6):

I guess:

> The answer is 0. Every third number is the difference between the previous 2 numbers.

Comment: the only issue i take with an answer like this is, it breaks up the single sequence into individual sequences of 3 entries. However, I like the answer as it answers the question.

Comment: Is this pattern the result of a series based on a starting rule that is then used to construct the rest of the series?  Like a Fibonacci series?  Or is this a pattern that you arbitrarily dreamed up according to a rule that cannot start a series?

Answer (score 1):

If I have to solve this question, you can do this.

> Subtract the first number from the second number.
>  
>  6- 1 = 5, 4 - 3 = 1 , 2 - 2 = 0

so, the series would be

> `(1, 6, 5), (3, 4, 1), (2, 2, 0)...`
>
>  Now after 0, the number would be 1.
>
>  Adding the triplets and dividing by 4, we get the next number.
>  
>  See, (1 + 6 + 5)/4 = 3,
>  (3 + 4 + 1)/4 = 2,
>  (2 + 2 + 0)/4 = 1

so, the series now would be

> `(1, 6, 5), (3, 4, 1), (2, 2, 0), 1`
>  
>  And then the next number in the series would be 0
>  
>  Check the middle number of the triplets,
>  it decreases by 2.
>  
>  6, 4, 2 and then comes 0

so, the series would be

> `(1, 6, 5), (3, 4, 1), (2, 2, 0), (1, 0, -1), (0, -2, -2), .........`

I hope I answered your question.

Answer (score -1):

If we can separate the unique sequence into three sequences of three numbers (165 341 22?), then perhaps the pattern can also be:

1 6 5

3 4 1 -

2 2 **4**

Comment: Why 224 specifically though?

Comment: Is a subtraction calculation between the first sequence of three numbers and the second one: 165 - 341 = 224. 4 would be the answer.

Comment: But 165 - 341 is -176, not 224 ...

Comment: They are sequences, not three-digit numbers. consider the units separately. for example, instead of 165, read one, six, and five. what I propose is the subtraction calculation between the last number of the first sequence (1 6 5) and the last number of the second sequence (3 4 1) to arrive at the third number of the last sequence (2 2 4), since the pattern seems to be repeated in relation to the first two numbers of each sequence: 1 - 3 = 2, 6 - 4 = 2. 5 - 1 = 4.